# server render script tag outside of webpack build

Tags: webpack

I am server rendering my react app like this:

```
export default ({ clientStats }: { clientStats: any }) => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  const context: any = {};

  const app = (
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <Application />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  if (context.url) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: context.url
    });

    res.end();
    return;
  }

  const { styles, js, scripts } = flushChunks(clientStats, {
    chunkNames: flushChunkNames()
  });

  const appString = renderToString(app);
  const { title } = Helmet.renderStatic();

  res.status(200).send(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        ${styles}
        ${title}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${appString}</div>
        <script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'init.js\' defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
`);
};
```

How can I reference a script that is outside of the webpack build?

I have an `init.js` file that does very little and I want to just reference it.

Where can I put it so that when the html is rendered, the script tag resolves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's so simple but a little complicated, first I explain all approach, then show in code.

You should consider a folder for all of `JavaScript` files that they are out of `webpack` build. Then put them into this folder and then import it as `externals` into `webpack` configuration. then set it as a separate vendor file, and absolutely output file name should make dynamically, so the `webpack` build its bundle and then copy your `JavaScript` file into dist folder. follow below:

```
// webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: {
        separateFile: `${srcRoot}/outFiles/yourJavaScriptFile.js`,
    },
    ...
};
```

By using the above code you consider a folder for your `JavaScirpt` file and import it into `webpack` configuration as a `externals` config.

Now you should import it as a separate file alongside your application files. see below:

```
// webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        myFile: 'separateFile', // <== its your external imported file
        app: `${srcRoot}/app/index.js`, // <== its your app file
    },
    output: {
        path: '/dist',
        filename: '[name].js' // <== dynamically make your JavaScript files,
                              //      so, in dist folder you can see app.js and
                              //      myFile.js file
    }
    ...
};
```

Definitely, you should import these files to your template function, hence:

```
  ...
  res.status(200).send(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        ${styles}
        ${title}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${appString}</div>
        <script src="app.js" defer></script>
        <script src="myFile.js" defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
 `);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `init.js` available in the root of your project build, so the server will use it when your file is rendered, you can see an example here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/blob/rebuild/src/server.jsx

Comment: if I just put init.js into the root of my project it is not copied over to the dist folder.

Comment: I ended up using the copy-webpack-plugin which was the answer to my problem

Comment: @dagda1, Using `copy-webpack-plugin` is a good way but it is not a proper way.

Comment: @AmerllicA why is it not a proper way?

Comment: `Webpack` is a module bundler, not a task manager, With that plugin, The `copy-webpack-plugin`, you use `webpack` as a task manager. I have never seen like it before, because of this I said, it is not a proper way. Adding `jQuery` to `react` application is a frequent question and the common answer is using `externals` of `webpack`. **But** of your project works now, it is ok, keep going to use `copy-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong using `copy-webpack-plugin` even in this situation. There are many ways to solve the problem. And I think, `copy-webpack-plugin` is the easiest way for this case.